# Return enum list instead of string in enum extension helper

Tags: c#, .net, enums, extension-methods

How can I convert the `GetWithOrder` methods to return the actual enum in the correct order?  It works for the string of the enum, but I want the actual Enum value, plus it needs to be generic of course.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EnumOrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
}


public static class EnumExtenstions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetWithOrder(this Enum enumVal)
    {
        return enumVal.GetType().GetWithOrder();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetWithOrder(this Type type)
    {
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enum");
        }
        // caching for result could be useful
        return type.GetFields()
                               .Where(field => field.IsStatic)
                               .Select(field => new
                                            {
                                                field,
                                                attribute = field.GetCustomAttribute<EnumOrderAttribute>()
                                            })
                                .Select(fieldInfo => new
                                             {
                                                 name = fieldInfo.field.Name,
                                                 order = fieldInfo.attribute != null ? fieldInfo.attribute.Order : 0
                                             })
                               .OrderBy(field => field.order)
                               .Select(field => field.name);
    }
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    [EnumOrder(Order=2)]
    Second = 1,

    [EnumOrder(Order=1)]
    First = 4,

    [EnumOrder(Order=3)]
    Third = 0
}

var names = typeof(TestEnum).GetWithOrder();
var names = TestEnum.First.GetWithOrder();
```

Comment: Just wonder - why would you have order of enum members which is not ordered alphabetically or by value?

Comment: Maybe because they are stored in a database, and adding new enums may need to be put in a certain ordered when displayed, but not related to the stored value.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to put the `EnumOrderAttribute` on the `Enum` values and simply check for it when iterating over `Enum.GetValues()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extension method for the variable of enum type makes no sense because you don't need a value of that variable - you need only enum type. So I would go with static helper class:

```
public static class Enum<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetOrderedValues()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return from f in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
               orderby f.GetCustomAttribute<EnumOrderAttribute>()?.Order ?? Int32.MaxValue
               select (T)f.GetValue(obj: null);
    }
}
```

Note: enum type has a non-static `value` field which actually holds the value of the enum. So you need to take only static fields if you want to list enum members.

Usage

```
var values = Enum<Fruits>.GetOrderedValues();
```

For sample enum

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Banana,
    [EnumOrder(2)]
    Apple,
    [EnumOrder(1)]
    Lemon
}
```

Output will be

```
[ Lemon, Apple, Banana ]
```

Members without `EnumOrder` attribute will go last, but you can change that behavior if you'll use some other default order instead of `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: This is insane :)